# add first entry into next line and shift data after comma & underscore from previous line to the next line

Tags: python, bash, shell, unix, awk

Data after underscore and comma will go to next line and data from beginning to pipe add before them.

sample data:

```
1.2.4.0/24|24151_24409_24406     
37.99.128.0/19|47794_47795,48695    
37.142.128.0/17|21450,65555
```

expected result should be:

```
1.2.4.0/24|24151    
1.2.4.0/24|24409    
1.2.4.0/24|24406    
37.99.128.0/19|47794    
37.99.128.0/19|47795   
37.99.128.0/19|48695   
37.142.128.0/17|21450    
37.142.128.0/17|65555
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: With bash: `while IFS="|,_" read -r -a col; do for ((i=1; i<${#col[@]}; i++)); do echo "${col[0]}|${col[$i]}"; done; done < file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk -F '[|,_]' '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) print $1 "|" $i}' file
```

Output:

```
1.2.4.0/24|24151
1.2.4.0/24|24409
1.2.4.0/24|24406
37.99.128.0/19|47794
37.99.128.0/19|47795
37.99.128.0/19|48695
37.142.128.0/17|21450
37.142.128.0/17|65555
```

The variable `NF` is set to the total number of fields in the input record.

Answer (score 0):

***gawk*** solution:

```
awk -F'|' '{ n=split($2,a,/[_,]/); for(i=1;i<=n;i++) print $1,a[i] }' OFS='|' file
```

The output:

```
1.2.4.0/24|24151
1.2.4.0/24|24409
1.2.4.0/24|24406
37.99.128.0/19|47794
37.99.128.0/19|47795
37.99.128.0/19|48695
37.142.128.0/17|21450
37.142.128.0/17|65555
```

---

- `split($2,a,/[_,]/)` - divide the 2nd field value into pieces defined by pattern `/[_,]/` and returns the number of elements created `n`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/((.*)\|[^_,]*)[_,]/\1\n\2|/;l;P;D' file
```

Replace the first `_` or `,` by the first two fields separated from the next two fields by a newline. Print the first line then repeat the process until all fields on the pattern space are accounted for.